# How to customize color of MUI range slider's track (in react/typescript using PCF controls) to include success, warning and error color?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, powerapps, model-driven

I have an imported range slider from @mui. But I need to customize the color of the slider track to show success(green color) from 0 to first slider thumb, warning(orange color) from slider thumb 1 - slider thumb 2 and last error( red color) from slider thumb 2 - 100.

I am using PCF controls in React/Typescript which is fairly new. All responses are appreciated.

Range slider from @mui (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhs1A.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please check out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As written at the moment if feel like you expect us to figure everything out for you.